# Book for learning ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm interested in learning about the MVC3 framework.

My background is MSc in Computer Science, with a professional experience in .NET2-4 and WebForms. I also have (very) little experience with MVC2, and some decent experience with JS and jQuery if that matters

I'm unsure which book to purchase to get me well off.

I've seen this book, Pro ASP.NET MVC 3 Framework, recommended in a few threads but its reviews are less than stellar. Including "Many errors in code", "lots of typos", "seems to be rushed out to be the first book on the subject". Therefore, I am reluctant to just go and buy this book in its first edition.

It seems the options are limited to

- [http://www.amazon.com/Pro-ASP-NET-MVC-3-Framework/dp/1430234040/ref=sr_1_2?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1312906757&sr=1-2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430234040)
- [http://www.amazon.com/Professional-ASP-NET-MVC-Jon-Galloway/dp/1118076583/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1312907008&sr=1-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1118076583)

And ofcourse, just looking at NerdDinner but I feel I'll probably miss a lot of cool features by taking that road...

Offhand note: I have no interest in learning Entity Framework at the moment.

What would be SO's recommendations for such a book?

Comment: I was going to ask this the other day. Figured it would be closed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the first book and posted a [review of it on Amazon](http://www.amazon.com/review/R39B4N5WNRHQ5R/ref=cm_cr_pr_perm?ie=UTF8&ASIN=1430234040&nodeID=&tag=&linkCode=).

Overall it is a decent book that does a good job, but there are issues as mentioned in my review and others.

I would still recommend you get it as a starter though as for me it has been a great starter into MVC.

Comment: I second this recommendation. Plus you don't need to mess with the Entity Framework if you use this book whereas (if I remember correctly) the nerd dinner does bring EF into the mix early on.

Answer (score 1):

I have the first one (and the first and second edition as well...) and I think all editions are excellent. I can wholeheartedly recommend Sanderson's books.